# Unexpected Type

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm very new to Java.  Having a problem with this block of code.  Attempting to find minimum number of coins needed to pay a certain amount (in example 398 cents).

I'm getting an error `unexpected type.  Required: variable. found: Value.` after I attempt to subtract on lines 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45 and 50. I want to subtract a value.  I think I have to use a method but I'm unsure how.  Any help would be very appreciated.

```
public class MakingChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 398;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
        int f;
        int g;
        int h;
        int j;
        int k;
        int i;
        int l;
        int m;
        int n;
        int o;

        if (a > 0) {
            if (a >= 200) {
                i = (int) a / 200;
                a - i * 200 = b;
            } else {
                a = b;
            }

            if (b >= 100) {
                j = (int) a / 100;
                b - j * 100 = c;
            } else {
                b = c;
            }

            if (c >= 25) {
                k = (int) c / 25;
                c - k * 25 = d;
            } else {
                c = d;
            }

            if (d >= 100) {
                l = (int) d / 100;
                b - l * 100 = c;
            } else {
                d = e;
            }
            if (e >= 10) {
                m = (int) e / 10;
                e - m * 10 = f;
            } else {
                e = f;
            }

            if (f >= 5) {
                n = (int) f / 5;
                f - n * 5 = g;
            } else {
                f = g;
            }

            if (g >= 1) {
                o = (int) g / 1;
                g - o = h;
            } else {
                g = h;
            }
            System.out.println(i + j + k + l + m + n + o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those expressions like `a - i * 200 = b;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assignment operation in Java language involves the following syntax:

**Variable = expression**

It first evaluates the expression on the right side and assigns the resulting value to the operand on its left. So going by this rule, LHS of an assignment must strictly be a variable which can be reference to primitive type, User Defined Type or an Array.

The blocks in your code which violate this principle are:

```
 a - i * 200 = b;
 b - j * 100 = c;
 c - k * 25 = d;
 b - l * 100 = c;
 e - m * 10 = f;
 f - n * 5 = g;
 g - o = h;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't say things like `g-o=h`. That's putting a value expression (`g-h`) on the left side of an assignment. If you want to assign `g-o` to `h`, then say `h = g-o`. You have a bunch of those.

Comment: @manetsus Why should that be a comment? This is a perfectly valid *answer* to this "question".

Comment: Why exactly does this 'not provide an answer to the question'? I'd like to know so I don't do it again, but I see a bunch of 'delete this post' recommendations. The answer is factual, and correct. What exactly is "not provided"? Or are you saying that the comment "should be in a comment" does 'not provide an answer to the question'?  Thanks.